# Xamarin method 'CGSize..ctor' not found

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just updated xamarin studio and then xamarin.forms package in my iOS project. It all builds fine, but when I try to run the app in the simulator I get this following error:

Method 'CGSize..ctor' not found.

I created a new solution. Build and run both works fine. But then I updated xamarin.forms package in the new solution. The same error appears again. So seems like whatever the new package has been rolled out is faulty.

When can we expect a fix and a new xamarin.forms package roll out?

Comment: Which version of `Xamarin.Forms` are using?

Comment: @SushiHangover reproduces on 2.2.0.43 for me

Comment: Getting this only when I add `<Label Text="Text" />` in XAML

Comment: Doesn't reproduce on 2.1.0.6529

Comment: Also works well on 2.2.0.31

Comment: 2.2.0.43 is the problem.

Comment: Same here with 2.2.0.43. For those who wants to downgrade (Using Xamarin Studio): in the Add Package dialog, enter "Xamarin.forms version:*" and select the previous v2.2.0.31.

Comment: I cannot confirm it just yet but this may be an XS issue as it's only occurring on the stable channel of XS. It doesn't happen in XS 6 nor on any of the build channels in VS.

Comment: Yes 2.2.0.43 is the problem.

Comment: @Paul it reproduces on VS for me.

Comment: Are you running stable channel only on both, though?