# System.MissingMethod Exception after upgrading to Xamarin Forms 2.2.043 on Xamarin Studio Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

After upgrading to the new version of Xamarin forms I'm getting a System.MissingMethod exception. Help!!!!!!!!!
Screenshot is here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPIAx.png. I've also posted this on Xamarin Forums. Still waiting for an answere from the Xamarin team. http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67725/system-missingmethod-exception-after-upgrading-to-xamarin-forms-2-2-043-on-xamarin-studio-mac#latest

Comment: What third party packages are you using in the project, if any? Are you able to pinpoint a specific cause for the exception by process of elimination?

Comment: Seems you are not alone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507846/xamarin-method-cgsize-ctor-not-found why don't you just roll back to an earlier version of Forms for now?

Comment: Yep, sounds like someone messed up the latest nuget push. I'd give it until Tuesday to see if a hotfix update comes out. This is a holiday weekend, so wouldn't expect there to be an abundance of engineers available to look into it. In the meantime, as Bill suggests - I would roll back to the prior release (which I've been using fine for a while now).

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue with a fresh project updated to 2.2.0.43, but something's obviously going on here. I'm personally not involved with the build process, but I'll try to find out what's going on and provide an update as able. As Keith above mentioned, since it's the holiday weekend in the US, everyone's patience is certainly appreciated. In the meantime, if anyone finds that one of the other update channels (beta/alpha) helps with the situation, do let me know.

Comment: This might be a stupid question to ask, but how do I roll back to an earlier version of the package on Xamarin Studio. I know how to do this on Visual Studio via the nuget package manager, but it's not very apparent on Xamarin Studio

Comment: @MadhavShenoy to downgrade on XS just Double click on the packages folder and search for Xamarin.Forms there will be 2 versions, select 2.2.0.31 there you go.

Comment: @MadhavShenoy - Adding to what Mario has commented, to see all versions for Xamarin.Forms in Xamarin Studio you can enter a package version search in the Add Packages dialog, for example: `Xamarin.Forms version:*` which will list all versions. Then select the one you want and install that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just pushed a fix to NuGet (2.2.0.45). Apologies for any difficulties.